# c++ std::ios_base::failure exception

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, exception, iostream

Standard(`N3337`) says (`27.5.3.1.1 Class ios_base::failure`):

> The class failure defines the base class for the types of all objects
>   thrown as exceptions, by functions in the iostreams library, to report
>   errors detected during stream buffer operations.

I have a simple test program which emulates restricted resource environment while using of std::ostringstream:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    rlimit limit;
    limit.rlim_cur = limit.rlim_max = 268435456;

    if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit)) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot set resource limit: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::ostringstream os;
    os.exceptions(std::ostringstream::badbit);

    try {
        auto iterations = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        while(iterations && --iterations) os << 'F';

    } catch(const std::ios_base::failure& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Caught: std::ios_base::failure" << std::endl;
    } catch(const std::bad_alloc& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Caught: std::bad_alloc" << std::endl;
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Caught: ellipsis" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In my environment (Linux, gcc 5.3.0) I got `Caught: std::bad_alloc` on `stderr`. [One of online compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3431d894273ba4d6) shows the same output.

The question is: why exception type is `std::bad_alloc` and not `std::ios_base::failure` ?

Comment: Because the exception isn't thrown by the iostreams library, but by the memory allocator?

Comment: Shoudn't it be recaptured and packed in a std::ios_base::failure exception? I'm working with iostream not with memory allocator.

Comment: You might think so, but no, the standard doesn't require that. There is also the problem that after a `bad_alloc` is provoked, there might not be any space left for creating another exception.

Comment: libc++ wraps std::bad_alloc into std::ios_base::failure exception, but looses error_code category and value.

Comment: I'm astonished to keep seeing questions which have `#include <stdlib.h>` and such in C++.

Comment: @Ohashi, I'm astonished to keep seeing comments which have nothing helpful to question.

Comment: I'm sorry to have annoyed you, but that's exactly why I posted it as a comment but not as an answer. Actually, it does help you; use of standard headers in such a way is deprecated in C++ long ago, and I just wanted to point it out for future newbies who seek their solution and stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os << 'F';` is `operator<<(ostream&, char)`, which is a Formatted Output Function, and, quoting 27.7.3.6.1[ostream.formatted.reqmts],

> the function endeavors to generate the requested output. If the generation fails, then the formatted output function does `setstate(ios_base::failbit)`, which might throw an exception.  If an exception is thrown during output, then `ios::badbit` is turned on without causing an `ios::failure` to be thrown. in `*this`’s error state. If `(exceptions()&badbit) != 0` then the exception is rethrown

As part of output, this function calls `stringbuf::overflow`, which is specified, in `27.8.2.4[stringbuf.virtuals]p8`, to perform reallocation. The difference between libstdc++ and libc++ here is the interpretation of the consequences of its allocation failure:

in libstdc++, it throws `std::bad_alloc` out of `stringbuf::overflow`, which unrolls the stack all the way to `operator<<` (technically, `__ostream_insert`), sets `badbit` and is rethrown, unmodified, as specified above.

In libc++, `std::bad_alloc` is caught inside `stringbuf::overflow`, and it makes `overflow` return `traits::eof`, which, in turn, makes the caller (in this case, `steambuf::xsputn`) return zero, which, in turn, makes the caller, `__pad_and_output`, wipe out the stream's rdbuf completely, which, in turn, makes its caller, `__put_character_sequence`, set both badbit and failbit. Setting of that badbit throws the `ios::failure` you caught.

Perhaps libc++ is technically correct in `stringbuf::overflow`: the standard says

> ''Returns:'' `traits::eof()` to indicate failure.

and it's hard to imagine a way for it to fail other than by allocation failure, but I think libstdc++'s interpretation is closer to the intent. (In libstdc++, `stringbuf::overflow` can still return `eof`, if the buffer capacity reaches `string::max_size` without first hitting `bad_alloc`)

Answer (score 0):

The error situation you are creating is not an error caused by stream buffer operations per se. At some point, you simply run out of memory and the allocator of the stream will throw a `bad_alloc`. This is the exception you are seeing.

Whether or not the `bad_alloc` should be rethrown as a ios_base::failure is debatable, since, in the end, the stream operation does fail. I am not surprised to see a `bad_alloc` situation in this case though.

Comment: Behavior differs at least between libc++ and libstdc++. libc++ captures std::bad_alloc and rethrows std::ios_base::failure loosing original exception details. So there is no portable way to determine exactly ENOMEM condition and handle it in some special way(like logging some constant string from DSS segment).